# how to get the value of client side variable in server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want to ask how to get the value of `var title` :

From this code :

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string script = "var title = $('.rsApt').attr('title');";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),"popup", script, true);
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not get the value while you're on the server side to begin with? If the element with the '.rsApt' class exists on the page, you can easily get the title while you're in the button click event and persist it.

Comment: i hope but the problem is: i have an advanced control , when click on the ".rsApt"div it should show dialog modal popup , so i can't access the server side click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to post it back, the script runs on the client so its value needs to be passed to the server.

A common method is to insert var title into a textbox, which then gets POSTed to the server.

Comment: Update panel won't make any difference, the value will still need to be POSTed to the server regardless

Answer (score 2):

you can:

1- add a HiddenField to your page.

2- get the value you want to store from your DOM element

3- save your value to the HiddenField value.

4- From your serverside code, read the HiddenField value.

5- smile.

6- Mark this post as (answer) :)

Comment: ههههه مرسي يامحمد ,,الموضوع مش بالبساطة دي,انا فكرت في دا ,بس مش هينفع عشان دي
special case.